# Entity Framework: creating standalone entity

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-5

Good day, stackoverflow.
My question is: when the entity from `DataContextModel` is instantiated somewhere in the code, does it already have references to the database record? Or can it be used as common `class` ? For example:

```
public void SomeMethod()
{
   var FirstEntity = new DBEntity(); //DBEntity is some entity from the database
   var SecondEntity = new DBEntity();
   var ThirdEntity = new DBEntity();
   DbSet<DBEntity>.Add(SecondEntity);
   DbSet<DBEntity>.Add(ThirdEntity);
   DbContext.SaveChanges();
}
```

So, will `FirstEntity` be affected somehow, or it will be removed, when the `SomeMethod` exits? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: In EF5 entities are simple classes, which do not know anything about persistence (well, if you don't use DataAnnotations). It's DbContext who tracks entities and determine their state (see ChangeTracker of context).

Comment: Additional but related remark: open your data context only when it's needed and close it as soon as possible. I have the impression that you are planning to open it once and never close it.

Comment: @L-Three thanks for your remark. It is just a code snippet for simplifying the question. In real project I am trying to follow such recomendations.

Comment: That's great, Artyom.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's just a plain class if outside the context.

But be careful, suppose this `FirstEntity` is referenced inside another object, as in:

```
var FirstEntity = new DBEntity(); 
var SecondEntity = new DBEntity();
var ThirdEntity = new DBEntity();
DbSet<DBEntity>.Add(SecondEntity);
DbSet<DBEntity>.Add(ThirdEntity);
SecondEntity.Sibling = FirstEntity;
```

When you save changes, if `Sibling` in the example is a foreign key reference, it will automatically add `FirstEntity` to the database.

Another example to be clear:

```
var Computer = new ComputerEntity();
var Motherboard = new MotherboardEntity();
Computer.Motherboard = Motherboard;
DbSet<ComputerEntity>.Add(Computer);
DbContext.SaveChanges();
```

This will save both **Computer** and **Motherboard** to the DB.